# Scrapy: return self._values[key] exceptions.KeyError: 'hour'

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

This is my pipelines.py

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    # run db query in thread pool
    query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item)
    query.addErrback(self.handle_error)

    return item

def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
    # create record if doesn't exist. 
    # all this block run on it's own thread
    tx.execute('select * from job where day = %s' % item['day'])
    result = tx.fetchone()
    if result:
        log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
    else:
        tx.execute(\
            "insert into job (id, company, day, hour, job, car1, car2) "
            "values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
            (item['company'],
             item['day'],
             item['hour'],
             item['job'],
             item['car1'],
             item['car2'],
             )
        )
        log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)

def handle_error(self, e):
    log.err(e)
```

I try to Insert to MySQL and receive the next error:

```
2013-09-17 16:19:34-0700 [scrapy] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\python27\lib\threading.py", line 781, in __bootstrap
        self.__bootstrap_inner()
      File "C:\python27\lib\threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "C:\python27\lib\threading.py", line 761, in run
        self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\threadpool.py", line 191, in _worker
        result = context.call(ctx, function, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
        return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)

      File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
        return func(*args,**kw)
      File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\enterprise\adbapi.py", line 448, in _runInteraction
        result = interaction(trans, *args, **kw)
      File "apple\pipelines.py", line 33, in _conditional_insert
        tx.execute('select * from job where hour = %s' % item['hour'])
      File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\item.py", line 50, in __getitem__
        return self._values[key]
    exceptions.KeyError: 'hour'
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Do you have `hour` field in your item class?

Comment: Thanks @alecxe, Thanks, I had "hour" in Item Class. Now I get another error: **submod = __import__(fullpath, {}, {}, [''])
  File "apple\spiders\apple_spider.py", line 19
    item['day'] = map(unicode.strip, site.select('//td[1]/text()').extract())
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent**  Can someone help me?

Comment: @Floriano this is an indentation error, check your indentation. IF you'll have problems, include the code of the spider into the question.